# What is the difference between "Milky way" and "Galaxy"?

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between "**Milky way**" and  "**Galaxy**"?

Comment: The galaxy we live in is called "the Milky Way". Always use 'the' before 'Milky Way'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Milky Way is the galaxy that we are in right now.

So "galaxy" is a general term, and the **Milky Way** is an example of a *galaxy*. Another example you might know is the *Andromeda Galaxy*.

Answer (score 0):

There are billions of Galaxies, the "Milky Way" is a specific galaxy, the one that we are in